# Convert malloc() to calloc()

Tags: c, malloc, type-conversion, calloc

I would like to convert malloc() to calloc(). I am confused about using calloc() in this example because it takes 2 arguments while malloc() only one. So it's correct with mine:

```
(byteBuffer)calloc(sizeof(byteBufferStruct), len + 1));
```

The example:

```
typedef struct byte_buf {
    size_t  len;
    uint8_t  *bytes;
} byteBufferStruct, *byteBuffer;


byteBuffer mallocByteBuffer(size_t len)
{
    byteBuffer retval;
    if((retval = (byteBuffer) malloc(sizeof(byteBufferStruct) + len + 1)) == NULL) return NULL;
    retval->len = len;
    retval->bytes = (uint8_t *) (retval + 1) ; /* just past the byteBuffer in malloc'ed space */
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: What is confusing? The first parameter to `calloc` is `num` and the second one is `size`.

Comment: `malloc(n)` is identical to `calloc(n,1)`

Comment: i am confused about the <num>

Comment: Well you want to allocate one of them so...

Comment: @mvp: no, the other way around: `malloc(n)` ~=> `calloc(1, n)` eg: `malloc(100*sizeof(char));` ~=> `calloc(100, sizeof(char));`. I know: `sizeof(char)` is 1, but I like to _see_ what I'm allocating memory for

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: you are wrong. From `man malloc`: The `calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)` function allocates memory for an array of `nmemb` elements of `size` bytes each. For our case, it is `n` elements of `1` byte each.

Comment: @mvp: saying `malloc(n)` is the same as `calloc(n,1)` would imply that _the first_ argument of `calloc` is the _size_ argument, whereas it clearly is the `nmemb` argument (as the man tells you). That's what I pointed out. `malloc(sizeof(struct foo));`, followed by a `memset` is ***not*** the same as `calloc(sizeof(struct foo), 1);`, the closest `calloc` gets would be `calloc(1, sizeof(struct foo));`. Your initial comment had the arguments in the wrong order: your `calloc` call would allocate an array of chars, an array of pointers would be impossible, for example

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: `calloc(n,1)` would allocate linear array of `n` bytes. So, for all intents and purposes, it is identical to `malloc(n)`. And, of course, it is the same as `calloc(1,n)`, because internally `calloc(m,n)` would simply call `malloc(m*n)` (followed by `bzero()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Both `malloc()` and `calloc()` return `void *`, which in C means [you should not cast the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comparing the signatures of the functions, we have:

- `void * malloc(size_t size);`
- `void * calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);`

Basically, the argument to `malloc()` is the product of the arguments to `calloc()`.

You can convert by just setting one of them to 1:

```
void * malloc_to_calloc(size_t size)
{
   return calloc(1, size);
}
```

Since the `nmemb` (number of members) to `calloc()` doesn't affect the actual structure of the memory in any way, this is safe.

Now we can use this to implement your allocation function (for clarity):

```
byteBuffer mallocByteBuffer(size_t len)
{
  byteBuffer b = malloc_to_calloc(len + 1 + sizeof *b);
  if(b != NULL)
  {
    b->len = len;
    b->bytes = (uint8_t *) (b + 1);
  }
  return b;
}
```

Note that `sizeof` is not a function. Also note the glaring asymmetry of asterisks that you get when you `typedef` away the asterisk. I don't recommend ever doing that.

Comment: it's clear now, thank you very much! (need to wait 6 min to mark it as answered)

Comment: I have read a long answer of you 2 months ago about not casting void (still remember your name^^). I will follow your suggestion. The code above is taken from Apple. They cast them, so newbee like me will make the same mistake.

Comment: @user3106115 Great! That answer is very likely the one I linked in my answer above, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
if((retval = (byteBuffer) malloc(sizeof(byteBufferStruct) + len + 1)) == NULL) return NULL;
```

do

```
if (NULL == (retval = calloc(1, sizeof(byteBufferStruct) + len + 1))) 
  return NULL;
```